# How to use wildcard for "Caddy2" 's path match?

Tags: path, match, caddy

I use Caddy web serve with "Caddyfile"
I want to let a path match which includes wildcard (*) to a URL, for example "https://example.com/bar/WILDCARD/baz", whatever WILDCARD is.
I wrote Caddyfile,

```
foo.com {
  file_server
  handle_path {
    /bar/*/baz
    root * ./
  }
}
```

But It only matchs "https://example.com/bar/*/baz".

How can I match whatever * is, for example  "https://example.com/bar/ABC/baz" , "https://example.com/bar/111/baz" or "https://example.com/bar/JELLYBEANS/baz".

Please mercy.